# Maximum number of tangents to two circles in affine geometry

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

How would one prove that the maximum number of tangents to two circles is 4, without recurring to the equations of the circles? I have found several ways of determining them (most of them using Calculus), but not some proof.

Comment: You have to be a little careful, because this isn't true if the two circles coincide - then every tangent to one is tangent to the other, but that just requires you to mention two distinct circles.

Comment: The argument here showing how to construct the tangents may offer a clue to a proof. https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/TangentToTwoCircles.shtml

Comment: @Mark Bennet He wants a maximal number of tangents.

Comment: @J Dionisio For non intersecting circles when one is not contained inside the other (external non-intersection circles) there are an infinite number.of tangents. If the point is given / or is fixed outside both of them then only there can be four tangents. So your question needs to be more specific.Depending upon $ (d-R_1-R_2 )$ center distance  =d their number varies.

Comment: @Narasimham an infinite number of lines who are tangents to two circles at the same time? Maybe I'm not understanding what you wrote, but I don't thinks that's right...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I know that. If the circles are distinct that is fine. But if circle A and circle B are the same circle, then they have the same tangents - an uncountably infinite number. If you don't specify distinct circles then this possibility is allowed.

Comment: I think this can probably be done by appealing to convexity and continuity by rotating a tangent around the first circle and considering what happens as it passes through points of tangency on the second and also through the centre of the second  (if it ever does). I can find configurations in the plane with $0,1,2,3,4, \infty $ common tangents

Answer (score 1):

Let $ax+by+c=0$ be an equation of the tangent to two circles with centers $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and radii $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively.

Thus, $$\frac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=R_1$$ and
$$\frac{|ax_2+by_2+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=R_2.$$
I think now we can see it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase it the best way, but what I meant with not using Calculus was actually not using a coordenate system and equations for the circles. Do you know of some other way?

Comment: @J. Dionisio It's obvious geometrically. Just draw two circles.

Comment: @J. Dionisio Actually, I did not use equations of  circles.

Comment: Yes you did not, I apologize. And I know it's obvious, but some proof must exist, no?

Comment: I wrote this proof. This system gives four tangents maximum.

Comment: A proof not dependant on distance and algebraic manipulation was what I meant. I updated the title to make it less open to interpretation